# ADO connect to SQL Server fails when wireless card used but cable to LAN works fine. use lpc:?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net, ado, wireless

A C++ point of sale application using ADO to connect to a default instance of SQL Server is failing when the application is used on a tablet PC with a wireless card for networking.

The application works fine on the tablet when a LAN cable is connected.

The testing people discovered that another server application that uses SQL Server was having a similar problem until they changed the settings to use Shared Memory connection to the SQL Server instance rather than TCP connection.

The connect string that we are using is as follows:

```
"Provider=MSDASQL;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=(local);DATABASE=%s;UID=; Password=;"
```

Reading this web page, it appears that in order to use shared memory connections, the `SERVER=(local)` keyword needs to specify `SERVER=lpc:(local)` however I am not sure of that.

The web page is [SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property From Microsoft MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx)

Comment: It's possible the SQL Server instance has been configured to listen on only certain IP addresses, perhaps only the wired network's one.

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion for something to check.  I will have the test team look into that.  Most of our customers just do the standard install and then do not touch it.  However for this particular customer, the deployment team may be doing something special as a part of a mobile point of sale terminal in a wireless cell environment.  The terminal is returned to the warehouse for pulling End of Day financial data using a LAN connection before going back on the shelf for the next use.

Comment: After making the change to the connect string for both point of sale application and the inventory application to use the SERVER=lpc:(local) keyword/value, the test team is no longer seeing a problem when the wireless cell card is being used.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810133/ado-error-16389-with-local-access-sql-server-database-connection-failing-when-u

Comment: Have you checked the Windows Firewall configuration of the PC?  I think the most likely cause is that Windows Firewall is blocking the TCP port for SQL Server when you join the wireless network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making the change to the connect string for both point of sale application and the inventory application to use the `SERVER=lpc:(local)` keyword/value, the test team is no longer seeing a problem when the wireless cell card is being used.

So the lpc: forces the use of shared memory.

See also this question on [ADO Error 16389](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810133/ado-error-16389-with-local-access-sql-server-database-connection-failing-when-u).

**Addendum for another component of the solution** (Oct-24-2016)

In the field sites that are using our point of sale we are also using Datacap Systems NETePay server to process Electronic Payment Transactions.

Due to the customer making a point of sale configuration error, since corrected, we recently discovered that the NETePay server ran into a similar problem. The XML response from the DSI Client-X control was an "Error" with an error code of 001501 and an error text that began "Database Error During ScratchWrite".

Remembering this problem and the solution we modified the settings for the Datacap Systems SQL Server instance, changing "Protocols for DATCAPINSTANCE" by changing TCP/IP from "Enable" to "Disable". After making this change the customer is no longer seeing the error.