# ADO error 16389 with local access SQL Server, database connection failing when using wireless card

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-connection, ado

We are sometimes seeing a database base engine connection problem with a C++ point of sale application that is using ADO to access a Microsoft SQL Express Server 2008 database.  The error code we are getting from ADO is 16389.  This issue appears to be related to using a wireless cell card in the terminal and when a standard LAN cable connection is used the problem is not seen.

The point of sale application is attempting to connect to the database engine in order to access a simple database of totals (currency and counts) for items that are part of the transaction data.

According to the documentation that I can find, this error means that connection requests to the database engine are not being honored possibly because the database engine is down.
[Losing Connections error 16389](http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-connect/3915/Losing-connections-with-SQL-2005)

We are seeing this problem after another application, an inventory application, which is using the same database engine instance is updating its own database with the starting inventory.  It appears from testing that if the inventory import step is skipped, the point of sale application is able to access the database and does not see the error 16389.

The inventory application and the point of sale application each has its own database, the databases are not shared.  However the same database engine instance is used for both applications.

The test team is currently investigating whether restarting the database engine after doing the inventory import will clear the problem. *Edit - the test team reports that restarting the database engine after doing the inventory import does seem to clear the problem.*

These applications work fine with an operating environment with a standard LAN cable connection to the terminal.  However when a wireless cell card is used, the test team is seeing this problem.  It appears from other documentation and testing that we must force the use of shared memory with the ADO interface.  The inventory application has not yet been changed but the point of sale application has.

My questions are:
 - what does the ADO error code 16389 mean?
 - what can an application do to recover from this error?

Comment: NOTE:   The test team reports that restarting the database engine after doing the inventory import does seem to clear the problem or rather that if restarting the database engine is added to the procedure, the ADO error is no longer being seen.

Comment: The provider of the inventory application has provided a release of his software in which he modified the connect string to force the use of the shared memory protocol for the database engine connection.  The test team has rerun this test, which was previously failing, some seven times (the setup is takes time) and have not seen the connect failure behavior.  We are currently of the opinion that the problem was from using the default TCP protocol in combination with the wireless card.  We are using SERVER=lpc:(local) in the connect string.